# Get location of finger press in iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am using Delphi XE5 to develop for Android (and iOS).

Using the InteractiveGestures from the Touch property in Delphi XE5 I can get a GestureEvent for Zoom, Pan, Rotate, TwoFingerTap, PressAndTap, LongTap and DoubleTap. All these comes with a TGestureEventInfo object where I can get the location of the event, eg. the coordinates of the fingers.

However, there does not seem to be a gesture that is just a simple tap/press. I know that the OnClick event is fired in this case, but the OnClick event does **not** come with a TGestureEventInfo object, so I cannot get the location of the tap. This seems like a really important event to get information about.

Am I missing something? How can I get the location of a simple tap gesture?

Comment: How about OnMouseDown()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the OnMouseDown/Up event:

```
procedure TForm17.Button1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; 
                                   Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin

end;
```

See you get X and Y coordinates.

```
procedure TForm17.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;
```

With OnClick however you get nothing.

**Caveat emptor**
Note that OnClick triggers after a MouseDown inside the control **and** a MouseUp also inside the same control, without there being any other MouseUp's or Down's. 
You should check for that if you want to have the same behavior as OnClick.

If you click inside a button and move outside it before releasing the click, it should not be registered as a `click`.

**Why does OnClick not give coordinates**
OnClick in FireMonkey is the same OnClick as in the VCL.
OnClick is the sum of OnMouseDown and OnMouseUp, as such there is no one place where the click took place, because the VCL did not want to choose between the Down or Up coordinate.

**My advise**
Fire on the OnClick event, but register the coordinate in the MouseDown.

```
procedure TForm17.Button1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; 
                                   Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  ClickGestureInfo.GestureID:= somethingNotAlreadyInUse;
  ClickGestureInfo.Location:= Point(x,y);
end;

function ClearGestureInfo: TGestureEventInfo;
begin
  FillChar(Result, SizeOf(Result), #0);
end;

procedure TForm17.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ClickGestureInfo.GestureID = somethingNotAlreadyInUse then begin
    //do stuff
    ClickGestureInfo:= ClearGestureInfo; 
  end;
end;
```

It normally serves no purpose to also record the OnMouseUp coordinates, because a click is only a click if the MouseDown and MouseUp are near in space.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I should have thought of MouseUp/Down, but I guess I was put off by the name since I was doing touch gestures.